# Filter by one property value and/or another AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I'm trying to filter an array of objects by their property value. I can do that when it comes to a single property value but not if I want to display both.

I am doing this on the controller level.

```
response = $filter('filter')(response, { insured: "Y" || insured: "B"}, true);
```

`response` is the response from my web service which returns array of objects.
These objects have a property of `insured`. In the example I'm using at the moment it only filters on the first condition `insured: "Y"` and ignores `insured: "B"` objects. I have also added `true` for an exact match filter.

What do I have to do to filter by one and/or another? I have looked at the documentation and other posts and they doesn't seem to have an answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
response = $filter('filter')(response, function(obj) {
  if (obj.insured == "Y" || obj.insured == "B") {
    return true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` in your controller instead:

```
$scope.filterByValues = function(item){
  return item.Insured == 'Y' || item.Insured == 'B';
}
ng-repeat="item in results | filter: filterByValues"
```